# Java8 streams : Filter data from two list of command object. Is there any other efficient way of what i am doing?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have two lists that hold `WorkflowCommand`s and `WorkflowInstanceCommand`s.

```
public List<WorkflowCommand> workflowList = new ArrayList<>();
public List<WorkflowInstanceCommand> workflowInstanceList = new ArrayList<>();

public class WorkflowCommand {

  int id;
  String name;
  String author;
  int version;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "WorkflowCommand{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", author='" + author + '\'' +
            ", version=" + version +
            '}';
  }

}



public class WorkflowInstanceCommand {

  long id;
  int workflowId;
  String assignee;
  String step;
  String status;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "WorkflowInstanceCommand{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", workflowId=" + workflowId +
            ", assignee='" + assignee + '\'' +
            ", step='" + step + '\'' +
            ", status='" + status + '\'' +
            '}';
  }
}
```

Need to print out above two results

1. Find all the workflows with their according Workflow instances.
2. Find all workflows having running instances and the number of those Workflow instances.

Code for first query:

```
workflowList.forEach(w -> {
    System.out.println("==workflow data=="+w);
    workflowInstanceList.stream()
            .filter(wi -> w.getId() == wi.getWorkflowId())
            .forEach(System.out::println);
});
```

Code for second query:

```
workflowList.forEach(w -> {
    List<WorkflowInstanceCommand> instanceCommands = workflowInstanceList.stream()
        .filter(wi -> w.getId() == wi.getWorkflowId())
        .filter(wi -> wi.getStatus().equals("RUNNING"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println("==workflow data=="+w+"===size=="+instanceCommands.size());
    instanceCommands.forEach(System.out::println);
});
```

**Is there any other efficient way of doing it?**

Comment: This is O(n^2). You can reduce that to O(n) by using Collectors.groupingBy() to create a Map<Long, List<WorkflowInstanceCommand>>, where the key is the workflow ID and the value is the list of WorkflowInstanceCommand with that ID. Once you have that map, you just need to loop through the workflowList and get the corresponding instances from the map.

Comment: Now, if you just have a few objects, the gain will be insignificant.

Comment: @JBNizet  I have already tried that as well.  Map<Integer, List<WorkflowInstanceCommand>> map  = workflowInstanceList.stream()                                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(WorkflowInstanceCommand::getWorkflowId));  But the problem is i want a map of Map<WorkflowCommand, List<WorkflowInstanceCommand>>  so that i can print workflow and their workflow instances. [Note : These are virtual command object not domain object.]

Comment: Read my comment again. You just need to loop through the workflowList and get the corresponding instances from the map.

Comment: @JBNizet Okay got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;
```

First query:

```
Map<WorkflowCommand, List<WorkflowInstanceCommand>> instancesByWorkflow =
    workflowInstanceList.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(WorkflowInstanceCommand::getWorkflowId))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .collect(toMap(e -> workflowList.get(e.getKey()), Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Second query:

```
Map<WorkflowCommand, Integer> numberOfRunningInstancesByWorkflow =
    .collect(
        toMap(
            e -> e.getKey(),
            e -> e.getValue().stream().filter(i -> i.getStatus().equals("RUNNING")).count()
        )
    );
```

and if you want to exclude WorkflowCommand with 0 instances you have to add this line to the second query:

```
.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue() != 0)
    .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```